# Unable to update cookie in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, cookies

I'm going nuts over this. I can write to a cookie, and then read it again. But at some point, i want to update the value it holds. Whenever i get the cookie again, i get the initial value, not the updated one. Below is the code i use for write/update and read of the cookie.

```
    private static HttpCookie WriteCookie(Guid siteId, string siteName)
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("UserSettings");
        if(cookie != null) {
            cookie.Value = EncryptObject(new UserSettingsModel { SiteID = siteId, SiteName = siteName });
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        }else {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings") { Path = "/", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Value = EncryptObject(new UserSettingsModel { SiteID = siteId, SiteName = siteName }) };
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        return cookie;
    }

    public static UserSettingsModel GetUserSettings(string username = null)
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("UserSettings");
        if (cookie == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
        {
            cookie = ResetUserSettings();
        }
        var userSettings = DecryptObject<UserSettingsModel>(cookie.Value);
        if (userSettings != null)
        {
            var siteId = userSettings.SiteID;
            var siteName = userSettings.SiteName;
            return new UserSettingsModel { SiteID = siteId, SiteName = siteName };
        }
        throw new SecurityException("You have no site attached to your user. Contact an administrtor.");
    }
```

`GetUserSettings` always returns the value that the cookie was initially created with. What's wrong?

EDIT:

I tried calling WriteCookie directly from a method in a Controller. The cookie was now set. I usually called WriteCookie via an Ajax request. Now, do i really have to write the cookie using JavaScript, or can i somehow just do it using WriteCookie?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check what is actually sent using fiddler? Look at expiration and path in particular.

Comment: I am using the Chrome browser, and using the integrated Developer tools, i can see that the cookie value is never updated. I wonder why

Comment: Look at the request and response headers to see what is going on.

Comment: AS far as i can see, no cookie is in the response headers. I can see the initial cookie value in the request headers though

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Cookies.Remove("UserSettings");
response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But I suspect that your actual problem is that you are calling the `WriteCookie` method and the `GetUserSettings` method in the same HTTP request which doesn't work as you might think it would or as you might expect it to.

The `WriteCookie` writes the cookie to **Response** so that it is available on **subsequent requests** but the `GetUserSettings` reads the cookie from the **Request** so you are getting the value of the cookie that was initially set when this request was initiated which of course is the old value. So after calling the `WriteCookie` to update the value of the user settings cookie, perform a redirect and only on the subsequent request use the `GetUserSettings` method.

Also in ASP.NET MVC you typically don't want to use the static `HttpContext.Current` object but use the abstractions that this framework provides to you. I know you wrote those 2 methods as static but you should have written them as an extension method to the `HttpContextBase` object for example. This way you could have called them anywhere where you had an instance of this abstract base class which ASP.NET MVC provides you in many common places during the lifetime of an HTTP request.

Comment: I tried removing and then adding, as you suggested. That didn't work. WriteCookie is called using an Ajax call. When this call returns, the page is refreshed and GetUserSettings is called. So the calls are in different requests. Don't mention the crippled Ajax calls and then reloads. I know this should be cleaned up.

Comment: The page is refreshed using "window.location.reload();" but i tried doing a Ctrl + F5 and i still get the old value. I realise that the else is only hit the first time. this is the way it should work. if there is a cookie, the cookie should be updated. otherwise it should be created

Comment: The problem was that i was calling WriteCookie from an Ajax request. I rewrote the code, so the cookie now is set via JavaScript. Works like a charm now. Thanks for pointing in the right direction

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for your comment. Yes its the ajax call. I was literally banging my head. I had re-written and removed the ajax call to  and now work great.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks for your comment. Yes its the ajax call. I was literally banging my head. I had re-written and removed the ajax call to var urlSetTheam = '@Url.Action("SetTheam")' + '?sTheamSelected=' + selectedValueText; and now work great.

Comment: Updating `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies` updates `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` (of questionable design choice, and it is what it is). Response cookies are seen/accessible immediately through the Request cookie collection. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219775/does-modifying-the-response-cookies-collection-also-change-request-cookies-in-n