# Does modifying the Response.Cookies collection also change Request.Cookies in .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Just want to check what i'm seeing, modifying the Response.Cookies collection also changes Request.Cookies?

Comment: AFAIK, it should. A response should write a cookie. A request should read it.

Comment: @series0ne - the *next* request should see the cookie, yes. But should the current request see the cookie that's just written to the response?

Comment: @HansKesting, I see your point...I'm guessing not? I have not looked into it that much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. Try creating a new page with the following in the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["newCookie"] == null)
    {
        Response.Cookies["newCookie"].Value = "Hello, world!";
        var myValue = Request.Cookies["newCookie"].Value;
    }
}
```

Clear your cookies and place a breakpoint on the closing brace of the condition. You'll see that `myValue` has the value `"Hello, world!"` on the *first* request.

Comment: That's what i'm seeing too, but only when the cookie is null. If the request cookie value is not null, then the response cookie is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, no. If you change the response cookies, it should not change the request cookies unless you specifically set them equal to each other or something like that.